# What is the simplest way to map a combination of flags into an enumeration?

Tags: c++, enums, boolean

I have been given an enum type that looks more or less like this

```
enum foo{
X,
XandY,
XandZ,
XandYandZ,
none,
Y,
Z,
YandZ,
someSpecialCase,
anotherSpecialCase
};
```

I have several message objects that pass through a pipeline, and a particular stage decides if this message has X or not, another one decides if it has Y or not etc. Ultimately the message needs to be labeled with one of these labels. I design the message object but the enum is already defined.  I don't want to assume any numerical values given to the enumerations. So I put boolean flags like hasX, hasY which can be individually set during different stages. Is there a better way than just writing a couple of layers of nested if-else clauses?

Edited for clarity
Edited again, changed the variable names.

Comment: did you try switch-case?

Comment: Can you be clear about the inputs? Are you given an enum value or are you given X, Y and Z from which you have to determine an enum value?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I need to assign one of these labels.

Comment: Depending on the number of cases and the nature of the problems, you can give 1 to 2 bit for certain state.

Comment: I think you would still need to explain more to hopefully get a good solution. For example, does `notXandY` mean `Z`? Or `notXandZ` actually mean `Y`? And what about those special cases; do you mean mean `notXandYandZ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the problem correctly then essentially what you are talking about is a multiplexer. i.e. combining several streams of information into one. This can be easily achieved using a look up table and the implementation of this is up to you.

You could combine the various input streams into a key object. *I've included some code below but don't have time to check / run it so please treat it as pseudocode rather than verbatim.*

**Using a map**

```
struct MyKey
{
    MyKey( bool X, bool Y, bool Z, bool SC1, bool SC2 ) :
        X_(X), Y_(Y), Z_(Z), SC1_(SC1), SC2_(SC2) {}

    bool X_;
    bool Y_;
    bool Z_;
    bool SC1_;
    bool SC2_;
};
```

You'll also need a `operator<()` function in order to use this in an associative container. Then you set up a mapping collection such as a map:

```
typedef enum foo FooEnum;
std::map< MyKey, FooEnum > myMap;
```

This map needs to be set up when your application starts and be loaded up similar to below:

```
myMap.insert( std::make_pair< MyKey, FooEnum >( MyKey(true,false,true,false,false), XandZ ) );
```

This maps X and Z only being true to `XandZ` so you need this for every permutation.

Once you come to do the check all you then need would be:

```
std::map< MyKey, FooEnum >::const_iterator it = myMap.find( MyKey(X,Y,Z,SC1,SC2) );
if ( it != myMap.end() )
{
    enum foo valueINeed = it.second;
    // ...
```

**Using a vector / array**

There are some variations on this. For example you could combine values of your input streams as bits in a mask (5 bits here) and use an array or vector of 32 elements to map each permutation to a separate element.

If you do that you could even create the collection at compile time. It will probably also run a bit faster though you'd have to test it. The drawback would be that the code is perhaps a little more esoteric but then again there's no law against documentation!